# c++ Parameters not passed into operator overload<

Tags: c++, object, overloading, operator-keyword

When creating an operator overload for a class "State", the operator that i've overloaded does not have any member variables initialized.

```
    bool operator<(const State m)const  
    {
       return (mDist < m.mDist);
    }
```

When adding a state into a priority queue which calls this operator, the value for mDist is not initialized

This is the code that begins the process

```
int row=0;
int col=0;
current.getBlank(row, col); // gets position of 0 in 3x3 int array


if (row > 0)
{   
    //creates a new state with current 3x3 array and postion of 0 as member variables
    State u(current, row, col); 
    u.swapUp();           // swaps 0 with position above it
    //n.findMDist(goal);  //calculates Manhattan distance from goal state
    nextMoves.push(u);    //push into queue
}
```

Any advice on what i should check that may cause the values to mot be passed to the operator overload?

Edit :

This is my state class.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef STATE_H_
#define STATE_H_
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 3;

class State
{
private:
    int board[SIZE][SIZE];
    int blankRow;
    int blankCol;
    State *parent;
    State *goal;

public:
    State() 
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            {
                setValue(i, j, counter);
                counter++;
            }
        int mDist = 0;
    }

    State(const State& s) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
                board[i][j] = s.getValue(i, j);
    }
    State(const State& s, int r, int c, State *g) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
                board[i][j] = s.getValue(i, j);
        blankRow = r;
        blankCol = c;
        goal = g;
        findMDist(*goal);
    }

    //get
    int mDist;


    //find
    void findMDist(State Goal);


    bool operator<( State m)const   
    {
        return (mDist < m.mDist);
    }

};

#endif
```

This is where mDist is implemented

```
void Game::next() {

int row=0;
int col=0;
current.getBlank(row, col);


if (row > 0)
{
    State u(current, row, col);
    u.swapUp();
    n.findMDist(goal);
    nextMoves.push(u);
}
if (row < 2)
{
    State d(current, row, col);
    d.swapDown();
    n.findMDist(goal);
    nextMoves.push(d);
}
if (col < 2)
{
    State n(current, row, col);
    n.swapRight();
    n.findMDist(goal);
    nextMoves.push(n);
}
if (col > 0)
{
    State n(current, row, col);
    n.swapLeft();
    n.findMDist(goal);
    nextMoves.push(n);
}
}
```

Comment: an operator doesnt have member variables. Did you implement the operator as a member of `State`? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: It's unlikely the culprit is in the `operator<()`, probably the `mDist` member is not initialized either in the "this" instance or in the passed `m` one (or both). Do you initialize `mDist` in the constructor, or somewhere else, before the `operator<()` is called? Can you provide the `State` code?

Comment: Check your copy constructor - you are passing a copy, not a reference.

Comment: Its seems that the value for mDist is correct up until it is pushed into a priority queue and then it calls the operator which has uninitialized mDist

Comment: What's with the `int mDist = 0;` in the constructor? That seems weird. You aren't doing anything with it after that.

Comment: Change `bool operator<(State m) const` to `bool operator<(State const &m) const`

Comment: Sorry that was from testing. 
I wanted to see if the priority queue was calling one of the constructors.

Comment: >Change bool operator<(State m) const to bool operator<(State const &m) const – Killzone Kid   

This makes this-> mDist unable to read memory

Comment: your constructor is not initializing `mDist` (but a same-named local variable that is shadowing the `mDist` member). I don't see the implementation of the `findMDist()` method, but it could be that you are not properly setting `mDist` there either...

Comment: You still didn't show `findMDist()`'s body. Post an MCVE. This piecemeal coaxing the rest of the code out of you is a waste of time. But you definitely didn't implement your copy constructor properly, as it does not copy all members. Coupled with you wasting resources and break semantics by taking a by-value copy in your `operator<`, that's why you have uninitialised members in that call.

Comment: the copy-constructor doesn't copy `mDist` and you are passing by value in the `operator<()`. Also note that storing pointers to other instances requires a great deal of care. Be sure to know what you are doing, or use a smart pointer like std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool operator<( State m)const
```

This passes by value and hence invokes the copy constructor. Here that is:

```
State(const State& s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            board[i][j] = s.getValue(i, j);
}
```

This only copies the `board`. It completely omits to do its job properly by copying all the other member variables, including the offending `mDist`.

So, `operator<` ends up working on an incomplete copy, in which multiple member variables are uninitialised, so you invoke undefined behaviour by reading them subsequently.

The fixes are:

- Implement a proper copy constructor that does its job, i.e. copies all member variables and results in all externally visible state being the same after it's done.
- Don't pass by value to the copy constructor, though, because that's a waste of resources and bad semantics. Pass by `const&` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Any advice on what i should check that may cause the values to mot be
>   passed to the operator overload?

When you pass a copy of `State` to you `operator<`, the `mDist` is not copied. You can add `mDist = s.mDist;` to your copy constructor (actually you might want to add it anyway), but it would be better to pass `State` by const ref to the comparator:

```
bool operator<(State const &m) const   
{
    return (mDist < m.mDist);
}
```

Also in your constructor you have local variable initialisation `int mDist = 0;` which makes no sense as it goes out of scope almost immediately. I think you meant `mDist = 0;` this will take care of your currently uninitialised member `mDist`.

Comment: This may be good practice, but it does nothing to explain the uninitialised members on its own, unless the OP failed to implement their copy constructor properly, in which case, that should be explained.

Comment: I think mDist should be calculated after the copy constructor. It need to change the object and the recalculate the mDist.  Its also worth mentioning that s.mDist is not initilised either in the operator.

Comment: Why do you think that anything would happen except what the copy constructor says to do? Since when does copying something also result in something else magically happening "after"?

Comment: @underscore_d Thanks for noticing

Comment: Your right i should probably get the copy constructor right first. I do have a n.findMDist(goal) that is called after the constructor that i was hoping would set the value for mDist based on an different State object.